# Export formatted Excel file from SAS

Tags: sql, excel, sas, enterprise-guide, vba

I am trying to export an excel file from SAS EG. I am using the code below and it works fine.

```
proc export dbms=excelcs
data= MONTH
 file="A:\D1\D2\FILE.xlsb" replace; 
 port=9621; 
 server="pwn59000.corp.ds.fedex.com"; 
  sheet='month'; 
run;

proc export dbms=excelcs
data= DAY
 file="A:\D1\D2\FILE.xlsb" replace; 
 port=9621; 
 server="pwn59000.corp.ds.fedex.com"; 
  sheet='day'; 
run;

proc export dbms=excelcs
data= YEAR
 file="A:\D1\D2\FILE.xlsb" replace; 
 port=9621; 
 server="pwn59000.corp.ds.fedex.com"; 
  sheet='year'; 
run;
```

So I get a file names 'FILE' with 3 sheets, month, year and day.
After I export the file, I added 3 more sheets to the excel file with a graph each for year, month and day and named the sheets as day1, month1 and year1. After that I hide the the sheets year, month and day so that the user can see only the graphs in sheets day1, month1 and year1. This file is exported out of SAS everyday. When the file got exported the next day, the sheets that should be hidden were no longer hidden but visible. Is there a way to hide the sheets using PROC export or any other procedure. Please help.

Thank You !

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  We post process SAS Excel exports with a C# utility do things like hiding sheets.

Comment: I would not think this is possible with the current tools.  When `ODS EXCEL` becomes available it might be a potential workaround (pre-production in 9.4 TSM1 from what I've heard).

Answer (score 0):

You could try exporting the dataset to CSV files and then use a data-connection from excel to import the csv files to the hidden sheets every time the Excel Workbook is opened.

Alternatively, try to use a libname statemet in SAS to reference the excel file:

```
libname xl pcfiles type=Excel unicode=yes port='YOURPORT' server='YOURSERVER' path = "YOURPATH\YOUREXCELFILE.xls" ;
```

Then delete the hidden sheet via

```
proc datasets lib=xl;
delete HIDDENSHEETNAME;
run;
```

And re-insert new data with

```
data xl.HIDDENSHEETNAME;
set YOURDATA;
run;
```

You need to repeat this for all of your hidden sheets of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide/unhide (and do a lot of other interesting things) using DDE-protocol.
Like this:

*First I create test Excel file with 3 sheets*

```
libname xlibr excel 'C:\Users\Dmitry\Google Drive\SAS\test.xlsx';
data xlibr.sheet1;
   set sashelp.class;
run;

data xlibr.sheet2;
    set sashelp.class;
run;

data xlibr.sheet3;
   set sashelp.class;
run;

libname xlibr clear;
```

*Now I have to open Excel programmatically (if it's already open it's ok)*

```
options noxwait noxsync;
filename sas2xls dde 'excel|system';

data _null_;
  length fid rc start stop time 8;
  fid=fopen('sas2xls','s');
  put fid=;
  if fid = 0 then do;
    rc=system('start excel');
    start=datetime();
    stop=start+10;
    do while(fid^=0);
        fid=fopen('sas2xls','s');
        put fid=;
        time=datetime();
        if time > stop then fid=0;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

*Now I send commands to Excel , actually simulating human-mouse-clicks:*

*1) open workbook*

*2) hide Sheet1*

*3) turn off errors (to save and close the file without possible pop-up dialogs)*

*4) save*

*5) close file*

```
filename sas2xls dde 'excel|system';
data _null_;
    file sas2xls;
    put '[open("C:\Users\Dmitry\Google Drive\SAS\test.xlsx")]';
    put '[workbook.hide("Sheet1")]';
    put '[error(false)]';
    put '[save()]';
    put '[file.close(false)]';
run;
```